# Feature resources are not installed after applying a patch

Tags: windows-installer, installation, patch

I'm struggling with an installation issue (which I think it may be caused by a glitch in the Windows Installer engine). However, I still want to ask about this just in case someone else could offer some useful insights.

I'll formulate this as a test case so it be easier to follow:

1. build an MSI setup (v1.0.0) containing three features (F1, F2 and F3); F2 feature contains a component whose key resource is "myApp.exe" (v1) application file
2. build an upgraded MSI setup (v1.0.1) which is patch-compatible with the previous ProductVersion and contains some new components added in the existing features and an updated resource for "myApp.exe" (v2) application
3. build a patch between the above MSI setups; NOTE that the patch fulfills all patch creation rules
4. install MSI v1 and select only F1 and F3 features for installation; F2 shouldn't be installed
5. install the patch
6. go to "Control Panel -> Programs and Features" and run "Modify", select the F2 feature to be installed and finish the (repair) installation

RESULT: the "myApp.exe" application file is not installed/copied in its target location even if from the log file it seems it should. Here are some relevant lines from the log:

```
FileCopy(SourceName=myA~1.exe|myApp.exe,SourceCabKey=myApp.exe,DestName=myApp.exe,Attributes=0,FileSize=713024,PerTick=32768,,VerifyMedia=1,,TotalPatches=1,,,CheckCRC=0,Version=2.0.0,Language=0,...)
...
MSI (s) (60:5C) [11:26:51:658]: File: C:\Program Files\Test\myApp.exe;   To be installed;   Smart patch;   No existing file
MSI (s) (60:5C) [11:26:51:658]: Redirecting file copy of 'C:\Program Files\Test\myApp.exe' to 'C:\Config.Msi\PT129.tmp'.   A subsequent patch will update the intermediate file, and then copy over the original.
```

Any thoughts are more than welcome.

Comment: Let us know if the file version of the exe was incremented in the patch, and my guess right now is that you may not be including whole files in the patch.

Comment: The EXE files have different versions (the one from the patch has an increased version). They are digitally signed, but they have the same size on the disk (maybe this matters somehow).

What do you mean by not including the **whole** files in the patch?

Comment: I don't think you said which tool you're using to create the patch, so I can't tell where it might be, but there is an option "include whiole files only". When set the entire file is in the patch, and when not set the patch is a delta that updates the file. In the Windows Installer docs it's here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370890(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hey Phil, it worked. Thx a lot. But I'm still wondering how the "IncludeWholeFilesOnly" flag affects my digitally signed application EXEs. If both versions of my app EXE are digitally signed how could Windows Installer include only a delta (between EXEs) in the patch setup?

Comment: If it's signed I think the certificate is cached on the machine so it can be checked every time the exe is run, to see it hasn't changed. So I assume that Windows can internally re-sign the the code or otherwise preserve the certificate. Windows is the OS, after all, and I assume we don't need protecting from it, only from malicious outsiders :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Phil I got this working by setting the [IncludeWholeFilesOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370890(v=vs.85).aspx) patch property to 1.